# Is it possible to run mongo replicaset commands using mgo driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Is it possible to run replica set commands like `rs.initiate()` and `rs.add()` using mgo driver from a golang application?

If yes, how??

Comment: Of course. All drivers are built on the basic principle of sending a "command structure" to the database. For mgo it is [`Run()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Database.Run), and the full list of [Database Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) is listed in the core documentation.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you give me an example of how to run ``rs,initiate()`` and ``rs.add()`` commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @alex-blex's answer which gave me the start. But this is what finally worked for me:

```
session, err := mgo.Dial("rs1.example.net?connect=direct")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

config := bson.M{
    "_id": "my_replica_set",
    "members": []bson.M{
        {"_id": 0, "host": "rs1.example.net:27017"},
        {"_id": 1, "host": "rs2.example.net:27017", "priority": 2},
        {"_id": 2, "host": "rs3.example.net", "arbiterOnly": true},
    },
}
result := bson.M{}
if err := session.Run(bson.M{"replSetInitiate": config}, &result); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Notice the following:

1. `?connect=direct` in the connection string.

   If not specified, the connection will timeout, probably because the replica set has not been initialized yet.
2. `session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)`

   Session mode should be `monotonic` as the default session used by mgo is `primary` which performs all operations on primary. Since the replica set has not been initialized yet, there wont be a primary and the operation (in this case, `replSetInitiate`) will just timeout
3. `"_id": "my_replica_set"` in the config

   For this to work, the mongo servers will have to be started with the replica set name `my_replica_set`. One way of doing that would be:

   ```
   mongod --replSet my_replica_set
   ```
4. As per [Mgo docs](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Run) use session.Run() for commands on the "admin" database

Answer (score 4):

An example for [rs.initiate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetInitiate/#dbcmd.replSetInitiate) command:

```
session, err := mgo.Dial("rs1.example.net")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()

config := bson.M{
    "_id": "my_replica_set",
    "members": []bson.M{
        {"_id": 0, "host": "rs1.example.net:27017"},
        {"_id": 1, "host": "rs2.example.net:27017", "priority": 2},
        {"_id": 2, "host": "rs3.example.net", "arbiterOnly": true},
    },
}
result := bson.M{}
if err := session.DB("admin").Run(bson.M{"replSetInitiate": config}, &result); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Same for [rs.add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetReconfig/#dbcmd.replSetReconfig) and any other rs.* helpers.